# Manipulate trigger interval in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

For a given scenario, I want to filter the datasets in structured streaming in a combination of continuous and batch triggers.

I know it sounds unrealistic or maybe not feasible. Below is what I am trying to achieve.

Let the processing time-interval set in the app be 5 minutes.
Let the record be of below schema:

```
  {
       "type":"record",
       "name":"event",
       "fields":[
         { "name":"Student", "type":"string" },
         { "name":"Subject", "type":"string" } 
   ]}
```

My streaming app is supposed to write the result into the sink by considering either of the below two criteria.

1. If a student is having more than 5 subjects. (Priority to be given to this criteria.)
2. Processing time provided in the trigger expired.

   ```
   private static Injection<GenericRecord, byte[]> recordInjection;
   private static StructType type;
   public static final String USER_SCHEMA = "{"
           + "\"type\":\"record\","
           + "\"name\":\"alarm\","
           + "\"fields\":["
           + "  { \"name\":\"student\", \"type\":\"string\" },"
           + "  { \"name\":\"subject\", \"type\":\"string\" }"
           + "]}";

   private static Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();

   private static Schema schema = parser.parse(USER_SCHEMA);

   static {
       recordInjection = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema);
       type = (StructType) SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schema).dataType();

   }
   sparkSession.udf().register("deserialize", (byte[] data) -> {
           GenericRecord record = recordInjection.invert(data).get();
           return RowFactory.create(record.get("student").toString(), record.get("subject").toString());
       }, DataTypes.createStructType(type.fields()));


   Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds1
           .select("value").as(Encoders.BINARY())
           .selectExpr("deserialize(value) as rows")
           .select("rows.*")
           .selectExpr("student","subject");

   StreamingQuery query1 = ds2
           .writeStream()
           .foreachBatch(
               new VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>() {
                 @Override
                 public void call(Dataset<Row> rowDataset, Long aLong) throws Exception {
                   rowDataset.select("student,concat(',',subject)").alias("value").groupBy("student");
                 }
               }
           ).format("kafka")
           .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
           .option("topic", "new_in")
           .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
           .outputMode("append")
           .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10000))
           .start();
   query1.awaitTermination();
   ```

Kafka Producer console:

```
Student:Test, Subject:x
Student:Test, Subject:y
Student:Test, Subject:z
Student:Test1, Subject:x
Student:Test2, Subject:x
Student:Test, Subject:w
Student:Test1, Subject:y
Student:Test2, Subject:y
Student:Test, Subject:v
```

In the Kafka consumer console, I am expecting like below.

```
Test:{x,y,z,w,v} =>This should be the first response 
Test1:{x,y} => second
Test2:{x,y} => Third by the end of processing time
```

Comment: @JacekLaskowski. The requirement is for per micro-batch. Hence I won't be needing to maintain the state.

Comment: Why don't you use `DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch` then? Seems the best match.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I am not able to group it by student name. I have updated the snippet in my question with the code I was using. Pls take a look and let me know what you think.